# панель меню VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Как вернуть горизонтальное расположение панели меню (файл, вид и т.д.)?
Сейчас оно у меня в виде меню-бургера и расположено в верхнем левом углу. [меню-бургер](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNQBv.png) .
Выбор параметра "строка-меню" не помогает (иконка меню-бургера перемещается в панель действий).
[меню-бургер в панели действий](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2G8j.png).
Версия VS Code: 1.78.1

Answer (score 0):

`Файл -> Настройки -> Параметры -> Окно -> Menu Bar Visibility` - попробуйте установить значение `classic` (по умолчанию)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, но не помогло. У меня в параметрах как раз и стоит classic

Answer (score 0):

Установите в настройках для `window.menuBarVisibility` значение `visible`.

Comment: я пробовал. не получается. Я все пункты этого параметра щёлкал - результата нет

Comment: Значит проблема в чем-то другом, именно это значение делает то, что вы хотите.